# Кодировка гостевой

Tags: php, кодировка

Здравствуйте. У меня есть WEB скрипт. По умолчанию в .htaccess задана кодировка cp1251 . И если зайти в гостевую и оставить там сообщение русскими буквами, то оно выводиться как "??????????????? ??? ?? ?". Это иза кодировки. 
Если в .htaccess указать кодировку utf-8 то русские посты в гостевой отображаются корректно, НО все остальное, включая заголовок страницы отображает непонятными символами. 
Можно ли как нибудь решить эту проблемму?
P.S. Посты в базу не записываються.

Comment: в разделе head указана кодировка?

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли как нибудь решить эту проблему?

Пересохранить "всё остальное" в utf-8

Либо, как сказано в другом ответе, исправлять работу с текстом где-то внутри. Потому что Форма присылает текст ровно в той же кодировке, в которой показывается она сама. То есть, текст портит обработчик. Если бы это была база данных, то решение очевидное. Но поскольку БД нет, а обработчик нам неизвестен, то другого ответа не будет.

Хотя я бы, впрочем, автору не верил, а заставил бы его найти соединение с БД и выполнить там запрос `SET NAMES cp1251`.

Comment: да, это конечно же решение. Но php файлов у меня на 45метров

Comment: Ну не вручную же! Даже под Windows это автоматизируется элементарно, простеньким bat/cmd-файлом и утилитой для перекодировки. Под *nix тем более.